# Search in a select tag phtml

Tags: jquery, html, tags

I'm trying to allow a search in a select tag but I've found on the Internet just resarch by option or Id;
I'd like to have a partial search inside on value.descrizione_job ( value.description_job). For example if I type "ill" if there is a description that has "ill" inside has to come out in the select

I attach you my phtml file:

```
var tabella ='<select class="inserisciJob">';
    if(jobsInserted){
     tabella +='<option value=""></option>'; 
      $.each(jobsInserted, function( index, value ) {
        if (value.dettaglio_job != value.descrizione_job && value.dettaglio_job != null && value.option_text != null)
            if (value.dettaglio_job != '') {
                tabella += '<option id="'+value.codice_job+'" data-codice-job="'+value.codice_job+'" data-descrizione-job="'+value.descrizione_job+'" data-da-autorizzare="'+value.da_autorizzare+'" data-dettaglio-job="'+value.dettaglio_job+'">'+value.option_text+value.dettaglio_job+'</option>';
            }else{
                tabella += '<option id="'+value.codice_job+'" data-da-autorizzare="'+value.da_autorizzare+'" data-codice-job="'+value.codice_job+'" data-descrizione-job="'+value.descrizione_job+'" data-dettaglio-job="'+value.descrizione_job+'">'+value.option_text+'</option>';
            }
      });     
    }
    tabella +='</select>';
return tabella;
```

I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("select").searchable(); 
});
```

but it doesn't work

Can anybody help me to solve this problem using jQuery?

This is the thing i'd like to have but using select tag instead of datalist:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").click(function(){
        $(this).next().show();
        $(this).next().hide();
    });

});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input list="brow">
<datalist id="brow">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>  
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much
Andrea

Comment: this is select-box options populate code. Where is search code? use `indexof()` to search partially.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
   $("select").searchable();
  });

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by data attribute :

```
$("select").find('option[data-dettaglio-job="' + search+ '"]').val();
```

If you want to search in option text :

```
$('select').find('option[text="'+ search +'"]').val();
```

`.val();` allows you to get the value of the option found.

You can use several types of search for the attribute : https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ (contains, starts by, ends by ...)

Comment: how can I say that search is the input of my keyboard?